# Rails - include? with object or object id

Tags: arrays, ruby-on-rails, ruby

I have an object called Company which has a method called owners that returns an array of User objects. I want to filter those companies by checking if the current user is in the owner's array. first I did something like this (which works):

```
Company.select { |c| c.owners.include?(current_user) }
```

However, I figured a more efficient check would be comparing only the ids instead of whole objects:

```
Company.select { |c| c.owners.map(&:id)include?(current_user.id) }
```

Can anyone help me understand if there is a difference between the two options?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There's really no difference between the two. Both are very inefficient and won't work if your Company table is large. They load all the Company records into memory, and furthermore call `c.owners` which fires an additional query on each of the records. This is called an N+1 query. You can address the N+1 part by using `Company.all.includes(:owners)`, but you'd still have the issue of loading everything into memory.

It's hard to give you exact code since you haven't shared your model definition (specifically, how the `Company#owners` association is defined). But I'll assume you have a CompanysOwners join table. In which case I would recommend the following code:

```
companies = CompanysOwners.where(owner: current_user).includes(:company).map(&:company)
```

This only fires off a single query, and doesn't load more records into memory than are needed. You could get rid of the `includes(:company)` part and it would still work, but be slower.

If your `Company#owners` association is defined differently than this, feel free to leave a comment and I can show you how to modify this for your needs.

By the way, to address your original question more directly ... under the hood, `c.owners.include?(current_user)` uses `==` to compare the records. And `ActiveRecord::Core#==` is comparing the IDs under the hood. You can see the source code here for proof of that: https://api.rubyonrails.org/v6.1.3.1/classes/ActiveRecord/Core.html#method-i-3D-3D. So they really are doing the same thing.

Comment: Thanks for the detailed explanation! I mentioned that 'owners' is a method (not an association) that returns an array (and not a relation), so the includes probably won't work? it creates an array based on some conditions and view permissions. so I guess I can't avoid this inefficient query without doing some refactoring?

Answer (score 1):

> I have an object called Company which has a method called owners that returns an array of User objects.

Well that's your problem right there.

This should really be handled on the model layer by setting up [an indirect association](https://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html#the-has-many-through-association):

```
class User < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :company_ownerships, 
     foreign_key: :owner_id,
     inverse_of: :owner
  has_many :companies, through: :company_ownerships
end

class CompanyOwnership < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :owner, class_name: 'User'
  belongs_to :company
end

class Company < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :company_ownerships
  has_many :owners, through: :company_ownerships
end
```

This will let you get the companies owned by a user by simply calling:

```
current_user.companies
```

This is vastly more efficient as it does a single query to fetch the associated records instead of loading the entire table into memory. This will return an `ActiveRecord::Relation` object and not an array which allows you to add additional scopes if needed:

```
current_user.companies.where(bankrupt: false)
```

Its also superior from a code design standpoint as the buisness logic is encapsulated in your models instead of leaking the implementation details all over the place.

It will also let you [`include`/`preload`/`eager_load`](https://bigbinary.com/blog/preload-vs-eager-load-vs-joins-vs-includes) to avoid n+1 queries:

```
@users = User.include(:companies)
             .all

@users.each do |user|
  # this loads all the companies in one single query instead 
  # of one query per user
  user.companies.each do |company|
    puts company.name  
  end
end
```

If you ever for some reason need to check if two records are related you want to use a join and where clause:

```
@companies = Company.joins(:owners)
                    .where(users: { id: current_user.id })
```